# Replace Value in Array with Previous Value Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

## Original Question

So if I have an array, s:

```
s= [4 5 2 5 8 4 11 6]
```

How would I go about replacing any number greater than 6 to be equal to the previous number. Giving s to be:

```
s=[4 5 2 5 5 4 4 6]
```

## Updated Question

I want to check if the number is at least double the previous number, and if so to replace with the previous number. Using the a different example to above, s:

```
s= [8 9 3 6 7 2 5]
```

Would be replaced with, s:

```
s= [8 9 3 3 3 2 2]
```

Comment: What output do you expect for `s=[5,7,9]`, could be `[5,5,7]` or `[5,5,5]` or is it impossible that there are sequences of numbers >6? Have you tried solving this using a for-loop?

Comment: For s=[5,7,9] it should give [5,5,5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is, iterate over all the values of your array and check if current value is greater than twice the previous value (you can replace the > with >= (greater than or equal to) if that's what you need. And whenever your required condition is met, you just need to copy value from s(i-1) i.e. the previous index to s(i) i.e. current place.

Your loop starts from i=2 instead of 1 because there is no previous value to check in case of i=1. In MALTAB indexing starts from i instead of 0 as in most languages.

```
s = [4 2 7 5 1];

for i=2:numel(s)
    if s(i) > 2*s(i-1)
        s(i) = s(i-1);
    end
end
```

Comment: For the `s=[5,7,9]` this code returns `[5,5,7]`. Putting it into a while loop until `ind` is empty would fix this.

Comment: This solution is even more efficient I think. It wont require n^2 time. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: When I do the above I get the error:    In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Comment: Edited the code. There was a slight bug, I didn't run the code I posted it first time. Sorry about that,

Comment: You can simply do `s(ind) = s(ind-1);`.  No `for` loop is necessary.

Comment: A simple `s(ind) = s(ind-1)` wont handle cases where there are multiple greater than 5 values lined up against each other like `[5 7 9]` case mentioned above

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Comment: Very true. Good catch! I forgot the recurrence relation for the duplicate numbers. I assumed they were all distinct.

Comment: How could I edit this to check if the value is double the previous value and if so to change it to the previous value? Such as    s= [0.4 0.2 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.6] would give    s = [0.4 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.2]

Comment: @MRaff16, Can you explain what you want with recurring values? e.g. `s = [4 2 7 5 1]` What I mean to ask is, if you change a value at a specific index, do you want to compare the next number with the updated value of the new number?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedRiaz I would want it to be compared with the updated value. Such as, using your above example,    s = [4 2 7 5 1] would give s = [4 2 2 2 1].

Comment: @MRaff16 Can you please update your original question to reflect these changes you want? So that a person who comes to this thread next would not be misguided?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`cummax`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cummax.html) function (introduced in R2014b):

```
s = s(cummax((s<=6).*(1:numel(s))));
```

Example:

```
>> s = [5 7 9 2 5 8 4 11 6]
s =
     5     7     9     2     5     8     4    11     6
>> s = s(cummax((s<=6).*(1:numel(s))))
s =
     5     5     5     2     5     5     4     4     6
```